# Active Record: Getting a User's Username with a user Id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these two classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And this is my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150723165743) do

  create_table "contents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "username"
    t.string  "password"
    t.string  "email"
    t.integer "content_count"
  end

end
```

My question is how I would be able to get and display a user's username from which I only have the user_id from the contents table.

And how would I do it the otherway around; having the user's username to get the user_id so that when I create a new content I can add the user's id to the user_id row in the table.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at `ActiveRecord` [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) when you get the chance.

> My question is how I would be able to get and display a user's
>   username from which I only have the user_id from the contents table.

```
# assuming user_id is in a field called id:

@user = User.find(id)
puts "username is #{@user.username}"
```

> And how would I do it the otherway around; having the user's username
>   to get the user_id so that when I create a new content I can add the
>   user's id to the user_id row in the table.

```
# assuming username is in a field called username:

@user = User.where("username = ?", username).first
puts "user id is #{@user.id}"
```